# mysql calculate machine hour variance by daily

Tags: mysql

i have a table 5000 lines like below. need search the previous machine hours reading and calculate different with current reading to column 'Variance',  each machine can have 3 or 2 different gauge.

can anyone give me a ideal. thanks.

```
Machine  Date       GaugeType   Reading  Variance
BM01    2021-10-20  ENG Hour    4502    
BM01    2021-10-20  L/H Perc    6509    
BM01    2021-10-20  R/H Perc    2404    
BM02    2021-10-20  ENG Hour    2738    
BM02    2021-10-20  L/H Perc    2479    
BM02    2021-10-20  R/H Perc    2520    
BM01    2021-10-19  ENG Hour    4502    
BM01    2021-10-19  L/H Perc    6509    
BM01    2021-10-19  R/H Perc    2402    
BM02    2021-10-19  ENG Hour    2738    
BM02    2021-10-19  L/H Perc    2475    
BM02    2021-10-19  R/H Perc    2516    
BM01    2021-10-18  ENG Hour    4500    
BM01    2021-10-18  L/H Perc    6508    
BM01    2021-10-18  R/H Perc    2402    
BM02    2021-10-18  ENG Hour    2726    
BM02    2021-10-18  L/H Perc    2473
```

Comment: You want a variance per machine/guage? ALSO what mysql version are you on?

Comment: Show finalized sample data (no "...") and desired output for this data. Also specify precise MySQL version.

Comment: Hi, im using Server version: 8.0.23. i have ablou 50 machine on this table, and each machine can have 1 or 3 gauge, we capture everyday. i want calculate variance per machine/guage/day to see how many working hours on that day.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, it's done.
here is code.

```
SELECT
    hourmeter.Machine,
    hourmeter.Guage,
    hourmeter.MeterEntryDate,
    hourmeter.Reading,
    hourmeter2.Reading AS proviousreading,
    (hourmeter.Reading-hourmeter2.Reading) AS variance 
FROM
    hourmeter
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM hourmeter ) hourmeter2 
    ON hourmeter.Machine = hourmeter2.Machine 
    AND hourmeter.Guage = hourmeter2.Guage 
WHERE
    hourmeter2.MeterEntryDate = DATE_SUB(hourmeter.MeterEntryDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

and output like this.

```
BM01    ENG Hour    2021-09-22  4424    4419    5
BM01    L/H Perc    2021-09-22  6506    6506    0
BM01    R/H Perc    2021-09-22  2376    2376    0
BM02    ENG Hour    2021-09-22  2670    2669    1
BM02    L/H Perc    2021-09-22  2394    2393    1
BM02    R/H Perc    2021-09-22  2419    2417    2
BM03    ENG Hour    2021-09-22  2727    2725    2
```

Comment: I'm glad you got this. Usually when you ask a question you share what you've tried and what is not working. Your question was too broad and is likely to get down voted. 

Next, when you answer you should add more details about how you fixed the underlying problem. Since there were no details in the question it's hard to be detailed in the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).